# How to pass special arguments in shell?

Tags: shell, hive, sh

```
sh abc.sh "--hiveconf db_name=${DB_NAM}"
```

I am trying to run this command but in my shell file I am not getting `DB_NAM`.

inside my shell it's running as

```
--hiveconf db_name=
```

Comment: Have you set  DB_NAM?

Comment: Try db_name-=${DB_NAM:?"DB_NAM not set"}" to assure it is set.

Answer (score 0):

--hiveconf is a `hive` command parameter, you do not need --hiveconf when passing variable to shell script.

If you want to pass named variables to shell script, you can pass variables in more clean way:

```
sh abc.sh db_name=${DB_NAM}
```

Parse parameters inside shell script:

```
#Inside the shell script
#parse parameters

for PARAM in "$@"
do
    KEY=$(echo $PARAM | cut -f1 -d=)
    VALUE=$(echo $PARAM | cut -f2 -d=)   

    case "$KEY" in
            db_name)              db_name=${VALUE} ;;
            something_else)       something_else=${VALUE} ;;     
            *)   
    esac    
done

#Now you can call Hive with parameter:    
hive -hiveconf db_name="$db_name" -f myscript.sql
```

And inside hive script  myscript.sql :

```
select * from ${hiveconf:db_name};
```

Comment: No need for `cut`: `KEY=${PARAM%%=*}` and `VALUE=${PARAM#=}`.

Comment: Or simply use `db_name=${DB_NAME} sh abc.sh`, and `db_name` will be passed via the environment, no additional parsing needed.

Comment: @chepner Yes it is the simplest way and maybe the best one if  DB_NAME is set